# Include non-modular header inside framework module with Allow non-modular includes set to YES

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8, reachability

**Background**
I'm building an API framework in Swift. I want it to include a `Reachability` class that can be used internally and externally.

**Status**
I've copied the source of the `Reachability` class provided by Tony Million, added the import statement to my header. The `.h` file is set to public in the `Headers` section of `Build Phases`. I've set `Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework Modules` to `YES` in both my project and target. Whenever I go to build the project, I get the error:

```
Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'MyFramework.Reachability'
```

on the line that imports `ifaddrs.h`.

**Question**
How can I get my project to build? Is there another framework I need to link against that isn't `SystemConfiguration`?

Comment: Nope, I just trashed the idea.

Comment: Same here, I could not get it to work either.

Comment: Are you still having this issue? If yes, can you provide an example project that demonstrates it? I tried to replicate but I didn't succeed (it's working for me).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this sample project: https://github.com/tomaskraina/swift-modules-reachability

It consists of a `ApiFramework` and a `ReachabilityApp` and demonstrates how to set it up so you can use `Reachability` both internally in the framework as well as externally - in the app.

[image: Xcode workspace screenshot]